# Как подключить exe как dll

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Возможно ли подключить exe файл как dll, я слышал что dll и exe похожие форматы.

Comment: Они не похожие, они одинаковые. Их формат называется PE (portable executable), а вопрос Ваш смысла не имеет (потому что подключают dll, а не exe).

Comment: пока два против одного что твой комментарий смысла не имеет а не мой вопрос.

Comment: Ваш вопрос не имеет смысла, потому что большинство EXE файлов, по понятным причинам, не экспортируют никаких функций, соответственно "подключать их как DLL" незачем. Разве что ресурсы вытащить. Другое дело если бы вопрос был "как создать EXE-файл, который можно при этом грузить как DLL".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У EXE и DLL точки входа (стартовые функции) организованы одинаково, но принимают различный набор параметров (ноль в случае загрузки как программы и [три в случае загрузки как библиотеки](http://scite.ruteam.ru/materials/cdllentrypoint.html)). Так что при попытке запустить DLL как программу получим непредсказуемое поведение.

Ещё, любой EXE, собранный из кода на C или C++, имеет прослойку между реальной точкой входа и `WinMain()`/`main()`. Эта прослойка, помимо всего прочего, производит полную инициализацию сишного и частичную инициализацию системного окружения (во втором случае это может быть, к примеру, настройка FPU). Поэтому загрузка EXE как библиотеки с очень большой вероятностью собьёт работу вашей, уже работающей программы.

Comment: получается, что у DLL  и у EXE принцип работы один но поведение разное?

Comment: @StanislavPetrov, да. Из этого, кстати, следует ряд любопытных явлений. Например, EXE может спокойно экспортировать функции, которые затем можно статически импортировать внутри подгружаемых DLL.